# How to input \Sexpr{ as verbatim in Sweave?

Tags: sweave, r

Building on my question here:
[Include Sweave input as verbatim](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35485/3419)

Is there a way to include the term `\Sexpr{` in the Sweave document as verbatim. For example, to write:

```
R code can be evaluated inline with the \Sexpr{} function:
```

Followed by an example of LaTeX code with the \Sexpr{} command in a verbatim environment.

My first guess was to write an R function that generates it:

```
sxpr <- function(x)
{
  paste(paste("\\\\","Se","","xpr{",sep=""),x,"}",sep="")
}
```

So that I could write `\Sexpr{sxpr('')}`, however, apparently Sweave runs many times and this does not work. My second guess was to make a seperate file with only `\Sexpr{` in it and input it. This works, but not in a verbatim environment.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do it on the LaTeX side instead of the R side.  Within a verbatim can be tricky, though; I used Verbatim from fancyvrb, which requires alternate characters for `\{}` that aren't used in your verbatim chunk, I used `|[]` below but you may need to change that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\ShowSexpr}[1]{\texttt{{\char`\\}Sexpr\{#1\}}}
\begin{document}
The result of \ShowSexpr{1+1} is \Sexpr{1+1}.
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=|\[\]]
Here's part of my Sweave file: |VerbSexpr{1+1}
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

See [ [How does one insert a backslash or a tilde (~) into LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9363)) for where I got the backslash code.  Also see [ [fancyvrb alternate commandchars and \textcolor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23091) ] for an example of Verbatim.