# How to comment in an R-chunk?

Tags: sweave, r, comments

I'm quite new to both R and LaTeX, but I'm trying to work with both, using Sweave.

I know you can comment in R using # and in LaTeX by using %. However, when I write a #comment in an R-chunk (between <<>>= and @) I get an error:

> Error: 'filename.Rnw' is not ASCII and does not declare an encoding
>
> Execution halted

I also tried it with % but that obviously didn't work (same error btw).

How can I put a comment in an R-chunk?

Answer (score 3):

Late in the game, but if you copied text into the Rnw file from another document type (e.g., Word), symbols such as " are coded differently.  Retype any symbols that you copied over (in entire document, not just R chuck).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 2):

Try `keep.source=TRUE`  in Sweave options. Or `\SweaveOpts{keep.source=TRUE}` in the preamble. Source: [Sweave customization](http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~stat782/downloads/Sweave-customisation.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

I think the real problem is that you have non-ASCII characters in your document, but you did not declare the encoding. Sweave was looking for a line like `\usepackage[foo]{inputenc}` in your source document; see `?Sweave` for details.

Answer (score 1):

I use comments in R chunks without a problem.  Here is mwe.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Test of Sweave without comment
<<>>=
2+2
@
Test of Sweave with single \# for comment
<<>>=
2+2
# Comment
@
\end{document}
```

And the output. 
[image]

Reference this [Include Sweave input as verbatim](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35485/include-sweave-input-as-verbatim) for example of getting the exact Sweave chunk in your output. (including the <<>>= and @)

Comment: Why is your comment being printed out?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by user29484, this sometimes occurs when you cut and paste into the Sweave document. It has happened to me several times when cutting and pasting from a pdf file in particular.

Text Wrangler (for Mac) has a tool called `Zap Gremlins...` in the `Text` menu. I open the Rnw file in Text Wrangler, apply this tool save the file and re-open in RStudio and am back in business.

Answer (score 0):

I would seriously consider using knitr rather then Sweave. It is very easy to use inside of RStudio or through your own editor.  I think it does a better job with options like this and more.

http://yihui.name/knitr/

https://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/authoring/overview